# `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize` not called on iOS 13

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, ios13

I have an issue with `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize` on iOS 13 beta. I am working on a plugin for NativeScript which uses the `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize` of the `UICollectionViewCell` to "measure and layout" the UIView that is in the cell. What I have been doing is:

- Manually call `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize` if I need to force a measure/layout of the `UIView` that is in the cell

or

- Wait for the OS to call `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize` and again measure and layout the `UIView` that is in the cell

It all worked perfectly until iOS 13 beta where it looks like there has been a change in the way the `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize` API is being called by the OS itself. In iOS 13 beta that API is not called by the OS at all and is rather using the [collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout/1617708-collectionview?language=objc) API to determine the size of a UICollectionViewCell. In iOS 12 and lower after the UICollectionView finishes its initial layout pass it calls each UICollectionViewCell's `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize` which allows you to give a chance for the cell to tells its size. In iOS 13 `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize` is no longer called.

Maybe it is something that I have to change or call on the UIView itself or the UICollectionView to make it work as it used to in iOS 12 but I am a bit lost in understanding if I am using the `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize` correctly.

So my question is, Should I expect the `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize` to be called by the OS automatically or this is simply a way to manually force a `UICollectionViewCell` to tell its size? And overall am I using it correctly?

Edit:

After further investigation, it looks like there is a change in the `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize` on iOS 13 (beta). It is no longer being called as it used to be when the `estimatedItemSize` of the layout is set. I created a project that shows the issue caused by this change in behavior and I will be reporting this to the iOS team. The project can be found [here](https://github.com/VladimirAmiorkov/iOS13-Self-Sizing-Cells-Issue). This issue leads to the behavior where you cannot implement "Self-sizing" cells when working with UICollectionView as the `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize` is no longer being called.

Comment: Did you already report that to apple?

Comment: Yes, I did but I am still waiting on a response from them. When I do or when I found an alternate solution I will update this thread.
I am following the release notes of each new beta version update but unfortunately there is nothing regarding UICollectionView for the time being.

Comment: Did you file a radar?

Comment: I send them feedback via their feedback service, if you know a better way please let me know. I just twitted at them.

Comment: Sounds good! Thank you!

Comment: Still no response tho :(

Comment: I found a solution/workaround that is not an official statement that I was hoping to see from Apple but I am still waiting on any response from them. You can see my finding as a response to the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57554694/3801632

Comment: I'm experiencing the opposite. The collection view is always self sizing when I only want it to use the size I give it from the delegate. What's odd is that it only happens on new cells I've been creating in Xcode 11. Older ones continue to work fine.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like there has been an internal breaking change with current iOS 13.0 beta (*simulator Version 11.0 (SimulatorApp-895.6 SimulatorKit-553.12 CoreSimulator-643.11*) that is not documented in the release notes. The change is that `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize` of an `UICollectionViewCell` is **no longer** called while the `systemLayoutSizeFitting(_:withHorizontalFittingPriority:verticalFittingPriority:)` is called.

So:

- `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize` is called on iOS <12 while
- `systemLayoutSizeFitting(_:withHorizontalFittingPriority:verticalFittingPriority:)` is called on iOS >13

## Solution/Workaround

So as a solution/workaround you have to duplicate your code from `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize` and place it inside `systemLayoutSizeFitting(_:withHorizontalFittingPriority:verticalFittingPriority:)`. While this is not perfect solution/workaround it at least gives us the a working solution for now, it is very much possible that this can change before iOS 13 is out of beta version and is released and is no longer required. Code example:

```
import UIKit

class FlickPhotoCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    func getCellSize(_ targetSize: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 50, height: 200)
    }

    // Only this is called on iOS 12 and lower
    override func systemLayoutSizeFitting(_ targetSize: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        return self.getCellSize(targetSize)
    }

    // Only this is called on iOS 13 beta
    override func systemLayoutSizeFitting(_ targetSize: CGSize, withHorizontalFittingPriority horizontalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority, verticalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority) -> CGSize {
        return self.getCellSize(targetSize)
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm experiencing the opposite. The collection view is always self sizing when I only want it to use the size I give it from the delegate. What's odd is that it only happens on new cells I've been creating in Xcode 11. Older ones continue to work fine.

Comment: What do you mean by creating in Xcode 11? Are you doing that via code or story boars or ? I personally am registering the cells via code and I get the above experience.

Comment: if you're using storyboard, you need check collectionview's estimatedsize value for "none" or "automatic", and this change is beyond annoying.

Comment: @VladimirAmiorkov hi, have you faced an issue while using custom view inside the cell. In the call of  UICollectionViewCell's systemLayoutSizeFitting, I am calling systemLayoutSizeFitting of my custom view. But it's crashing sometimes. Any idea?

Comment: @schinj Can you share with me the error message you get?

Comment: @VladimirAmiorkov https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65917495/exc-bad-access-kern-invalid-address-0x000000000000000c-specialized-systemlayouts Here I have posted the question.